# I firstly installed ChromeOS with Brunch and then Kubuntu on my Laptop. Now grub doesn't recognize Chrome OS. How to add Chrome OS to Grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, chromeos

I am new to the Linux world. I recently installed Chrome OS with Brunch on my laptop. Later I installed Kubuntu but grub does not recognize the ChromeOS I installed earlier. It only allows me to boot into Kubuntu.

Here's what my partitions look like:
[image]

What should I do to add ChromeOS into grub as an option so it works as dual-boot?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You've provided release info, but have you tried `sudo update-grub`? and did it show.  On some older releases I've needed to `mount` the other OS for it to be recognized; but it will depend on what *fs* you are using for your chromeOS (eg. I've had issues with BTRFS & a few others). At last resort you maybe able to `chainload` to chromeOS but sorry I have no experience with it; and I'd first try and get `grub` & look at specifics on *fs* (file-system) in use etc, release details you've not provided.

Comment: Was ChromeOS *working* before you installed Kubuntu? Looking at your messy partitions, it looks as though you've tried several times to get the thing in a working state. If ChromeOS was working, then you'll need to change just one file in Kubuntu. If ChromeOS wasn't working, then you'll need to do a lot more ...

Comment: Thank you for replying to me. @guiverc I've just tried sudo update-grub command, but it didn't work. Grub didn't show up and the system just booted into Kubuntu as usual.

Comment: @matigo Thank you for the comment. The ChromeOS was working fine before I installed Kubuntu. It was the only OS on the laptop. The laptop is not a Chromebook, I installed it with Brunch. The reason why my partitions look messy is that I tried several other distros before settling on Kubuntu. Thank you for pointing that out though. Guess I will need to clean it up a little bit. What file you mentioned should I edit?

Comment: did you manager to fix this ? please accept the below answer if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

So long as ChromeOS was properly working before installing Kubuntu, you can add a record for the OS in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` that looks like this:

```
menuentry "Chrome OS" {
 insmod part_gpt
 insmod ext2
 set root=(hd0,gpt3)
 linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3 init=/sbin/init rootwait rw noresume console=tty2 i915.modeset=1 loglevel=1 quiet noinitrd tpm_tis.force=1
}
```

<sub>Be sure to set `gpt3` and `sda3` to the correct partition number if I've incorrectly identified the boot partition for ChromeOS.</sub>

Note that the above configuration is assuming that your storage device is a GPT device. If it's not, you will need to remove the `insmod part_gpt` line from the configuration and change the root to `(hd0,X)` where `X` is ChromeOS's root partition number ... probably 3.

Once done, update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Now you can reboot and find a record for "Chrome OS" in your boot list.

<sub>**Note:** If ChromeOS was not working before installing Kubuntu, you will need to confirm the `STATE_DEV=${ROOTDEV_TYPE}1` setting in the `/sbin/chromeos_startup` on ChromeOS is changed to `${ROOTDEV_TYPE}3` (or whatever the root partition for ChromeOS happens to be). Only numbers `1` through `8` are valid, so you may want to be careful given the number of partitions on your storage device.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I checked /etc/grub.d/ but there is no such file called 40_custom. Should I create it myself?

Comment: The terminal returned the following after entering `sudo update-grub2`:   `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub.d/40_custom.cfg: menuentry: not found`